# Export WiFi x509 client certificate

Tags: wi-fi, backup, wpa2, wpa-supplicant

My Android (4.4) device has a WiFi configured which uses WPA2-TLS authentication with client certificates.

I got my hands on the wpa_supplicant configuration and the relevant entry looks like this:

```
network={
        ssid="fobar"
        key_mgmt=WPA-EAP IEEE8021X
        eap=TLS
        identity="000123"
        password="000000"
        ca_cert="keystore://CACERT_fobar_WPA_EAPIEEE8021X_TLS_NULL"
        client_cert="keystore://USRCERT_fobar_WPA_EAPIEEE8021X_TLS_N"
        engine_id="keystore"
        key_id="USRPKEY_fobar_WPA_EAPIEEE8021X_TLS_NULL"
        engine=1
        proactive_key_caching=1
}
```

How can I get hold of the certificates and the key?

Answer (score 0):

Go to :

> `/data/misc/keystore/user_0`

And find the file's with similar name like below :

```
USRCERT_fobar_WPA_EAPIEEE8021X_TLS_N
```

Comment: good idea, but how to make of the file contents?

Comment: i think these files automatically stored in this directory.and also, this information can help you : `ca_cert="keystore://CACERT_fobar_WPA_EAPIEEE8021X_TLS_NULL"
        client_cert="keystore://USRCERT_fobar_WPA_EAPIEEE8021X_TLS_N"` for find and save.